# onClick button not executing the function inside a form [Not the type=submit problem]

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Please, look at the HTML **form** below:

```
<form>
  <input  name="tesla" id="tesla">
  <button type="button" onclick="tesla()">BUTTON</button>        
</form>
```

When I try to execute the function **tesla()** by **clicking** the button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
tesla is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick 

(index.html:14)
onclick @ index.html:14
```

I get this error in two situations:

1 - If I set the function **NAME** equal to the input **NAME**
[name="tesla" AND onclick="tesla()"]

Or

2 - If I set the function **NAME** equal to the input **ID**
[id="tesla" AND onclick="tesla()"]

(In the example above, I used all three equal)
When I use different names, I get no errors.
Why is this happening??
This is a very simple piece of code, this should not be happening...

Obs. The function I tested with:

```
function tesla(){
  console.log("text");
}
```

Comment: Browsers will define global variables of the same name as the name (or id) of form elements.

Comment: Interesting question -- I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: This is related to why giving an input in a form an id of "submit" is a bad idea.